# Can't run phpdoc (bad interpreter error)

Tags: pear, phpdoc

Installed phpdocumentor via PEAR, but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
bash: /Users/username/pear/bin/phpdoc: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to symlink those two files with no success. What can I do to run `phpdoc`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/Users/username/pear/bin/phpdoc` and change the first line from

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/bin/php
```

to a path that actually exists.

Alternatively, run

```
php /Users/username/pear/bin/phpdoc ...
```

---

You should also fix the PHP binary that PEAR uses by first verifying it:

```
pear config-get php_bin
```

then changing it with

```
pear config-set php_bin /path/to/php
```

After re-installing phpdoc via pear it would work now.